# Add image between Recycler view items

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

is it possible to add an image with a link between a specific number of items. For example show an image every 10 items.
is it possible to do this?

Comment: Please explain your question more.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 i want to show an image (like an ad) multiple times inside a recycler view and i want to show it once every 10 items. the user will be scrolling the recycler view and every 10 items he will see an ad

Comment: So whats the issue? Add the image in your adapter data after every 9th item.

Comment: Have you ever tried it my friend?Post the code , so far you have tried it.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 i didnt try it because i dont know how! as far as i know there an item.xml file that will difine how every item of the recyclerview will look like so i dont know will i add the ad

Comment: See no one is going to write the code for you. I am going to suggest the way to do it. First add your image data after every 9th item in your adapter data. When you load it check for `i % 10 == 0`. If its true load the image else your actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use multiple layout

-check this example [recyclerview-with-multiple-different-layouts](http://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-recyclerview-with-multiple-different-layouts/)

Answer (score 4):

You can have different kind of cells in a recyclerview.

Have two cell types: one for your regular items and the other for your linked images.

To achieve that:

Override `public int getItemViewType(int position)`

and handle it in `public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)` by using a switch statement based on the values returned in the above function.

For details see : https://android.jlelse.eu/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-item-types-dfba3979050

Answer (score 0):

Create a model for image links and integer variable for every link increase integer variable by one.
in adapter class check the int value, if int value is 10 or more implement your own or add custom objects